# Why is my jquery not working in Rails 3 using js.erb

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

vote_up.js.erb:

```
  1 $(".total-vote-count").val("#{@plusminus}")
  2 $("a.vote-up-off").addClass("vote-up-on")
```

My view:

```
 11     #voting
 12       #vote-count
 13         = link_to "Vote Up", {:controller => 'reviews', :action => 'vote_up', :id => @review.id},
 14                              {:class => "#{@vote_up_status}", :remote => true }
 15       
 16         %span.total-vote-count
 17           = @review.plusminus
 18 
 19         = link_to "Vote Down", {:controller => 'reviews', :action => 'vote_down', :id => @review.id},
 20                                {:class => "#{@vote_down_status}", :remote => true}
```

I know that the js.erb does render because when I do something on the entire vote-count div to replace it with text("what is up") it works.  But what I have doesn't :(

Help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Errr, I'm a noob, but in your js.erb, aren't you supposed to use `<%= =>` ? Like `$(".total-vote-count").val("<%= #{@plusminus} %>")`
 ?

Comment: oh yes, right --- before I just  had plain text and it still wasn't working though....